# How to find the CRLF line separator in the code

Tags: git, newline

I was committing a file when PyCharm showed me this error.

```
You are about to commit CRLF line separators to the Git repository
```

What is this line separator? Is there some strange character in my code? How can I find and manage it?

Comment: carriage return, line feed is used by Windows. Your repo/git settings must be enforcing a standard. PyCharm can change your line endings and you can set a default.

Comment: So you suggest to click on 'Fix and Commit' which means `git config --global core.autocrlf input will be called`. But what are the consequences? This change can affect also my colleagues?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the separator using command:

```
git grep -Il $'\r'
```